# buttonset() span not working properly with IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the lastest version of jquery and I themed a list of checkbox with it.

Im IE7 every time a user clicks on the buttonset span(which is pretty much the whole button as far as the users are concerned) the page gets scrolled up about 600pixels up.

This is really not a good thing, especially since those radios are located pretty far down a page with a scrolling bar, can you image the users who want to select 60 options? Having to scroll back down every time?

I literally use nothing else but this to these my radios:

```
$(".prettyme br").replaceWith(''); //fix RadioButtonList Bug
$(".prettyme").buttonset();
```

You can see a live version of my bug at: http://www.apff.org/fr/inscriptions.aspx?i=18

Use IE7, scroll down and click on one of the many checkbox buttons with a C- in front of the number.

I know its related to the span located inside of the label creating the button image, if I attach a click event on one of those spans and make it return false, I do not get this behavior anymore.(It stops the checkbox from being checked and unchecked on the label click however)

How do I stop this infernal Jquery behavior?

Comment: Be fair; it sounds more like infernal IE7 behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by saving the scrolling bar position before the button is clicked, and bringing the scrolling bar to its initial position later.

```
/*
 * The code below fixes a bug in Internet Explorer.
 * The bug happens when a gender button is being clicked,
 *  and scrolls the page down.
 * Don't replace it by 'return false' or 'preventDefault()',
 *  it will prevent the radio button from being selected.
 */
$('.ui-button').live("click", function(event) {
  // save the vertical scrolling bar's position
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  $('.box_radio').click(function(){
    // bring the scrolling bar at its initial position
    if (scrollTop)
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop);
    scrollTop = false;
  });
});
```

`box_radio` is a parent element of the button.